# CSS - css framework (like blueprint) for a 100% page width design?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I've used [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) in the past for designing websites and it helped a lot.

I'm now considering developing a new site, but this time it will be a 100% width site (think google groups page). Blueprint had a liquid "fork" some time ago, but after some tests I didn't find it quite useful for 100% width (it's ok for 90%-ish pages).

So I'm on the hunt for a new framework.

For now the best candidate seems to be [elasticss](http://elasticss.com).

Is it a good alternative? Are there any others I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deciding to use [MALO](http://code.google.com/p/malo/), because it was small and had no associated javascript. My second best was [yaml](http://www.yaml.de/en/), but I dind't like its license.

EDIT: now I like [oocss](http://oocss.org/) more.